# Controller Design: Where to handle AJAX requests?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, model-view-controller, controller

I have two resources, `Article` and `Comment`. An article can have many comments. A non-AJAX, HTML request is made to load an article's `show` page. The page contains a comments section with a pagination feature that works via AJAX. My question is, where should I put the logic that handles the pagination requests? In `articles_controller` or `comments_controller`? Even though the primary resource is an instance of `Article` and the AJAX request is being made from the `Article` `show` page, the `Article` resource isn't really involved with paginating comments. Thus, it makes more sense to me that the logic should be processed in `comments_controller`, but I can see how the other side would work as well.

Comment: If it feels like it makes more sense in the `comments_controller`, then put it there. In some situations you could go either way and there's no clear right or wrong answer.

Comment: @joshua.paling I've gotten happy with putting the logic in the comments controller and following this pattern for other AJAX requests. If you'd like to make your comment an answer, I will accept it. Thanks a lot for the response. On a side note, I deleted my first comment because I realized I had initially misinterpreted you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it feels like it makes more sense in the comments_controller, then put it there. In some situations you could go either way and there's no clear right or wrong answer.